# Yii2 БД PostgreSQL ошибка при сохранении модели в цикле

Tags: postgresql, yii2

Yii2 БД PostgreSQL, при сохранении в модель циклом по массиву, при создании строки в БД выдает ошибку:
(PDOException: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint.)
Если убрать **$this->id = null;** ругается на не уникальность ID при сохранении второй строки.
(PDOException: SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "order_book_pkey")
При создании атрибута id выбрал SERIAL.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class OrderBook extends ActiveRecord
{

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'order_book';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['order_id', 'book_id'], 'default', 'value' => null],
        [['order_id', 'book_id'], 'integer'],
    ];
}

public function saveOrderBook($books, $order_id)
{
    foreach($books as $book){

        $this->id = null;
        $this->isNewRecord = true;
        $this->order_id = $order_id;
        $this->book_id = $book;
        if(!$this->save()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'order_id' => 'Order ID',
        'book_id' => 'Book ID',
    ];
  }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне выполнить это сохранение в цикле.

Comment: 1) зачем вы насильно `null` ставите? 2) зачем вы выставляете `isNewRecord` ? 3)  Что приходит в переменной `books`?

Comment: 3) order_book - это промежуточная таблица, которая хранит id заказа и id товара $books - массив ключей товаров, если товаров в заказе больше одного то добавляются дополнительные строки с разными id товара и одинаковыми  id заказа. 2) isNewRecord  что бы не перезаписывалась строка 1) null что бы обнулялся id и срабатывал авто инкремент.

Comment: зачем вам в manyToMany таблице id? Похоже на изначально какой-то дичайший костыль

Comment: Задача, из админки в таблице GridView по чекбоксу выбирать нужные товары, таблица GridView  завернута в форму, при отправке которой в контролер передается массив с товарами. Далее нажимается кнопка создания заказа, создается заказ и в связную модель сохраняются данные о № заказа и товарах относящихся к нему, не знаю может и костыль, но в курсе WebForMySelf в связную таблицу данные сохраняли способом перебора массива, вот я и решил применить его. Подскажите если вам не сложно как можно это реализовать лучше.

Comment: если они в manyToMany умудрились запихнуть левое поле id, то они сильно скатились. В вашем случае, проще всего создать пустой заказ, и потом массивом в MTM подрисовать данные. Вариант получше - самому получить id следующего заказа, и потом сохранить новый заказ уже с вашим id

Comment: MTM на то и MTM что есть id1 и id2, третьего значения там не надо. В laravel есть такая практика, точно видел в мануале, но, и там, очень специфичная ситуация. Пока что не вижу предусловий, чтобы у вас было больше 2 колонок

Comment: Действительно, а зачем мне вообще нужен этот столбец id в промежуточной модели, как то я об этом и не подумал, информацию о товарах в просмотре заказа я же без него осуществляю с помощью МТМ.

Comment: перепишите свой ответ пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно воспользовался советом Alex Khonko, за это ему спасибо.

Оставил в промежуточной таблице два атрибута удалив инкрементный id. Сохранил пустой заказ с редиректом на страницу редактирования, там получил id заказа из модели и там же добавил товары (в данном случае книги), отправил форму с ключами товаров, получил массив и методом saveOrderBook сохранил

контролер:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {   ///редактирование сотрудника и клиента
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    if (\Yii::$app->request->post('selection')) {
        $order_book = new OrderBook();
        $items = Yii::$app->request->post('selection');
        if ($items && $order_book->saveOrderBook($items, $model->id)) {
            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Книги успешно добавлены');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'ошибка добавления книг');
        }
    }
```

saveOrderBook()

```
    public function saveOrderBook($books, $model_id)
{
    foreach ($books as $book) {

        $this->isNewRecord = true;
        $this->order_id = $model_id;
        $this->book_id = $book;
        if (!$this->save()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```